# Button inside repeater

Tags: asp.net, post, submit, repeater

I have a repeater on my page, page1, which displays product details in each item. Each item has "select this" button and I post to page2. I want to display which product selected on page2. Sounds simple but couldn't solve it for hours. Any idea? My itemtemplate on page1 looks like this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
<ul>
<li><%#Eval("Product_Name") %></li>
<li><%#Eval("Product_Code") %></li>
...
<li>
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Select this" PostBackUrl="page2"/></li>
</ul>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Only solution came to my mind getting button number with Request.Form but this will make me add one more query to get nth product. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it would apply to your situation, but usually, this problem is solved by using the ItemCommand pattern :

First subscribe to `ItemCommand` event of your repeater (same as subscribing to `ItemCreated`/`ItemDataBound`)

```
yourRepeater.ItemCommand += yourRepeater_ItemCommandHandler;
```

where the handler is :

```
protected void ItemCommandHandler(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.CommandName=="SelectThis")
  {
      var productCode = e.CommandArgument;
      //...
  }
}
```

then, in your markup :

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Select this" CommandName="SelectThis" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Product_Code")%>' />
```

never tried this pattern when posting to another page. Hope this will help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Is a `PostBack` necessary? If not i suggest you to solve this problem with this approach:

Replace your `asp:Button` with `asp:HyperLink` and pass productId or productCode in a `QueryString`. Here's an example:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <ul>
        .
        .
        <li>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="hlSelectProduct" runat="server" Text="Select this" NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("~/Page2.aspx?Product_Code={0}", Eval("Product_Code")) %>' />
        </li>
    </ul>
</ItemTemplate>
```

and on page2.aspx just retrieve product from database by using Product_Code

Answer (score 0):

I cannot use querystrings because I don't want everything to be shown on url. And I tried ItemCommand but it requires page to post itself. For the same reason, I couldn't use onclientclick either.

However, I managed to solve the problem by using Jquery. I created a hiddenfield outside of repeater and created a jquery function to handle button clicks. I put the product id value in each buttons' rel attribute and assigned it to hiddentext's val by that function. Jquery function did work before page post and since my buttons all have postbackurl addresses, it worked without problem.